# addEventListener click executed before clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to pass over parameters in the click function.

```
var albums = document.getElementsByClassName("album");
for(var i = 0; i<albums.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(albums[i].id).addEventListener("click", goAlbum(albums[i].id), false);
}
```

However, the function `goAlbum` gets executed when it is created, and then the function won't execute anymore.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`goAlbum` was getting executed because you called the function. You weren't "creating" a function. What you intended to do was supply `addEventListener` with logic to execute when something is clicked; that logic being "invoke `goAlbum`". To do this, wrap the function call in an anonymous function.

```
function toArray(list) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(list);
}

var albums = toArray(document.getElementsByClassName("album"));
albums.forEach(function (album) {
    document.getElementById(album.id).addEventListener("click", function () {
        goAlbum(album.id);
    }, false);
});
```

Additionally, because [it is unwise to create functions in a `for` loop](https://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop), I have refactored your code to use `forEach`. I need to convert the `NodeList` returned by `document.getElementsByClassName` to an `Array` in order to use `forEach`, hence the `toArray` function.