# How do I pass a variable to a function with event listener without the function executing randomly

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dom-events

I have 4 divs, when a user clicks one of the boxes, I want to send a variable to a function (e.g user: *clicks div1*, eventlistener: *sends 1 to the function). And I have a problem, I don't know how to phrase it but I'll try to explain it with code:

```
function print(x) { // my dummy function for testing
    if (x == 1) {
      console.log('1');
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
document.querySelector(".first").addEventListener('click', print); //this executes on click, 
//but prints "error" and won't help me in the long run


document.querySelector(".first").addEventListener('click', print(1)); //this executes on load,
//prints 1 and won't help me either because I want it to execute only on click
```

I found one solution ([addEventListener click executed before clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245040/addeventlistener-click-executed-before-clicked)) but it didn't help me because I'd have to copy paste 4 identical functions and most probably slow my page and make my code really messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply an anonymous function or an arrow function `() =>` reference to the `click` event handler where you can supply an argument to the `print` function

Also you can use the [`Function.prototype.bind(thisValue, arg1, arg2, ...argn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to send the function reference with `this` set to a value:

```js
function print(x) { 
    if (x == 1) {
      console.log('1');
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
//document.querySelector(".first").addEventListener('click', print); 

document.querySelector(".first").addEventListener('click', () => print(1)); 

//or

document.querySelector(".first").addEventListener('click', function() {print(1);});

//or

document.querySelector(".first").addEventListener('click', print.bind(null, 1)); //here this is null
```

```html
<div class="first">Click here</div>
```

Comment: Works great! I'll accept this as an answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 4 divs.

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
<div class="fourth"></div>
```

Then you can add event listener to ALL 4 DIVS like this:

```
function print(x) { 
    if (x == 1) {
      console.log('1');
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  }


document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', () => print(1)));
```